# setting multiple paths to PERL5LIB in Windows command line

Tags: windows, perl

So I set PERL5LIB to a certain directory in my Windows command line using this

```
set PERL5LIB = c:\path\to\dir
```

I want to know if there is a way to set multiple paths in the same command line to PERL5LIB.

```
set PERL5LIB = c:\path\to\dir1
set PERL5LIB = c:\path\to\dir2
set PERL5LIB = c:\path\to\dir3
etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you set multiple paths by semicolon separating them.

```
set PERL5LIB = c:\path\to\dir1;c:\path\to\dir2;c:\path\to\dir3
```

Comment: `s/Generally/In Windows/`

Comment: Yeah, sorry - my gist was that it works similarly to other Windows path environment variables